# How should I respond to someone says "Did you down vote me"?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

What is the proper response to someone who says "Did you down vote me?".

I know I'm supposed to write a comment when I down vote anyone, but I don't know how should I respond to the down vote question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lets address this first "I know I'm supposed to write a comment when I down vote anyone" - simply not true.  Downvoting does not require or need a comment. If you *choose* you may offer an explanation, but it is certainly not the expectation nor something you should feel guilty about not doing.

Second, if somebody asks you - either answer truthfully or don't answer, that part is up to you. But its generally poor taste of the first person to ask.